# OracleConnectionCacheImpl not working with ojdbc7

Tags: connection-pooling, deprecated, oracle12c, ojdbc

The following code was working with ojdbc14 but started to give error with ojdbc7 which i had to use for connection with oracle 12c.

```
OracleConnectionCacheImpl occ = new OracleConnectionCacheImpl();
occ.setURL(dbprp.getProperty("DB_URL"));
occ.setUser(dbprp.getProperty("DB_USER"))
occ.setPassword(dbprp.getProperty("DB_PASS"));
occ.setMinLimit(Integer.parseInt(dbprp.getProperty("CON_CACHE_MIN")));
occ.setMaxLimit(Integer.parseInt(dbprp.getProperty("CON_CACHE_MAX")));
occ.setCacheInactivityTimeout(Integer.parseInt(dbprp.getPropert("CON_CACHE_ABANDON_TIMEOUT")));
occ.setCacheScheme(dbprp.getProperty("CON_CACHE_SCHEME"));
```

I know that  **OracleConnectionCacheImpl** deprecated from 11g onwards so how i work around this error. please help.